# Logistic regression - the model is significant in predicting the DV, yet the percent correct decreases

Tags: logistic, predictive-models

How can this be? My thoughts are that while the percent correct decreased from 80.8% to 80% with the model, perhaps the model is regarded to be a significant predictor due to the specificity having increased. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think there is enough here to allow any really useful comment, except possibly that no regression is designed to maximise "percent correct", whatever that is. You have puzzling results, but you need to tell us what you are trying to do, what you did and what results you got in much more detail.

Comment: Your title and tags contradict each other. I'd guess you mean "logit regression" in your title. "Log regression",  not I think a standard term, is not a synonym for logit.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I conducted a logistic regression, the dependent variable being verdict (not guilty/guilty). I entered all five independant variables simultaneously. Results indicate a percentage correct of 80.8% before the IVs are entered. I understand this is already quite high due to a ceiling effect with the majority having reported a guilty verdict.

Comment: The classification table reports overall percentage correct of 80% after the model is implemented. I was confused by this because the omnibus test of the model shows that the model performs better than block 0, yet the percentage correct decreases. What I noticed, however, was an increase in specificity with the model, where a handful of participants are correctly identified in the not guilty category.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have 2 observations, an event ($X_1=1$) and a non-event ($X_2=0$). Say our first model "predicts" probabilities  $P(X_1)=.55$ and $P(X_2)=.45$. If our decision rule for prediction of an event is based on a $.5$ probability threshold, then this first model is perfect (given our decision rule and the estimated probabilities). But notice the probabilities are close to $.5$ (close to that of getting tails on a coin flip!).

Now we change the model and the new probabilities are $P(X_1) =.95$ (much closer to observed $1$) and $P(X_2)=.51$ (not very different from the previous estimate, but importantly, crossing the threshold!). Considering the same decision rule for prediction, our predictions are not perfect anymore. However, considering the change in estimated probabilities, now we have a much better fitting model overall.

This brief discussion is based on the decision rule for prediction which I have assumed you are using. If your view of your model's performance is based on correct guesses, then the performance of your model depends on how you make guesses. Chances are, you could merely change the decision rule and see a completely different evaluation of your model's performance.

There are many ways to measure model performance.  Some more imperfect than others.

It's probably worth mentioning that such a decision rule is not an inherent element of logistic regression. Logistic regression models the probability of events, not dichotomous guesses about whether they occurred.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. I thought that the overall percentage correctly classified, in this instance, 80% with the model, indicates that the model accurately identified 80% of the observed participants' verdicts. Yet, this is less what was being correctly indentified without the model- however it appears that the distribution of correct verdict changes between actual observed guilty and not guilty verdicts. With the model, no not guilty verdicts are correctly identified. My question is: does this explain why the model is considered to be worthwhile?

Comment: First define how you are classifying predictions. Then ask yourself if your classification scheme (which is not an inherent part of logistic regression) is reasonable. My goal was merely to point out that the "correct guesses" view of performance is flawed in certain ways.

Comment: i.e., if the estimated probability for a specific event is $0.49$, should you really just guess it will not happen? And furthermore, call yourself right if it doesn't happen, and wrong if it does? Seems shaky to me. I'm assuming a classification scheme that sets a threshold at $0.5$, which may or may not be yours.